# How do I add a progress bar to my kendo grid cell

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, progress-bar

I need to do progress bar in kendo grid cell to calculate time for 10 days depending on the date I specify

my code in kendo grid is. columns. Bound (p => p.DateOfReminder). Title ("").ClientTemplate("<div class='progress'></div>"). Sortable(false). Width ("12%");

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the progress bars in the grid dataBound event.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  var grid = e.sender;
  //find all progress bar divs in grid body
  grid.tbody.find(".progress").each(function(e) {
    //get the dataItem for the current row
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    //init the progressbar and set the value
    $(this).kendoProgressBar({
        max: 10,
        value: dataItem.progress
    })
});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OjicAvob)**